# Using Symfony Autoloader

Tags: php, symfony, autoload, autoloader, psr-0

I am just testing out migrating my application to Symfonies autoloader from the SplAutoloading im using right now.

My Application Structure is

```
> Components
> Models
    > Core
        Test.php
Index.php
```

My Test.php is like this

```
namespace Core;

class Test {    
}
```

Trying to load it in my index.php

```
define('__WEB_ROOT__', __DIR__);

//Symfony Class Loader
require_once __WEB_ROOT__ . '/Components/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$oLoader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$oLoader->registerNamespaces(
array(
    'Core' => __WEB_ROOT__ . '/Models/Core/'
)
);
$oLoader->register();

use Core\Test;

$oTest = new Test();
```

No idea why the class cannot be loaded like this? Any help? What is the correct usage here

Answer (score 0):

The set filepath should not include the namespace name. So if `Core\Test` is located in `__WEB_ROOT__/Models/Core/Test.php`, you should register the `Core` namespace to `__WEB_ROOT__/Models`:

```php
$oLoader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Core' => __WEB_ROOT__ . '/Models/',
));
```